# Add-In Commands Ribbon shows in Excel Online but not in Excel for Windows

Tags: office365, office365api, excel-addins, office365-apps, office-js

I have an Add-In with its own Ribbon that works fine in Excel online but does not show the Ribbon in Excel on Windows [1]. There, it only shows the default task-pane.

To make sure it does not have to do with my own manifest, I verified this with the OfficeDev simple Sample manifest [2]. The only two modifications I did to the xml file are replacing 2 instances of Document with Workbook.

Also, I have verified this on two computers.

Why could that be?

[1] Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1003) 32-Bit on Windows 10
[2] https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Simple/Manifest/SimpleAddin.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your build of Excel doesn't support add-in commands. You'll see add-in commands after 16.0.6769.0000 or later in Excel and Word.

Comment: Adding to Michael's answer, Add-in Commands require build 16.0.6769.0000 or later.  See [Office Updates](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Office-Updates-a118ec61-f007-492f-bfa5-5a6f764d5471) for the latest builds.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about Office 365 vs Professional/Professional Plus. Are these two completely separate development tracks for the Office Dev teams? We've just grabbed the latest MSI of Office Professional Plus, and we're on v16.0.4591.1000, which appears almost two years behind the Office 365 version number!